# MongoDB and Heroku Deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Alright stuck here. This app - https://budget-vacation-offline.herokuapp.com/ .

I have added my environment variables to Heroku as well. There is an error in the console too regarding the mongo network. What am I missing? Happy to link the repository if needed. This is my error locally.

App running on port 7894!
(node:1177) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Answer (score 0):

The error mean that your app need to connect to an instance of mongodb, which not available on the address you set(localhost). So to fix the error you need to provide the correct url to connect.

To get a mongodb instance you can host your own mongodb server or use online mongodb service such as mongodb official service [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).

Previously, there is exist an add-on for mongodb [mLab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) on heroku that you can use but it seem that it's has been discontinued.